# How can I draw an area between two functions f(y) and g(y) with x as the horizontal axis?

Tags: plotting

I am a newbie looking for some help to tweak this code:

```
f[y_] := y^2 - 2;
g[y_] := y;

plot1 = Plot[f[y], {y, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
plot2 = Plot[g[y], {y, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red];

fill = Plot[{f[y], g[y]}, {y, -1, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
   FillingStyle -> LightGreen, AxesOrigin -> {0, -2}];

Show[plot1, plot2, fill, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"Y", "X"},
 PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

What should I do to get the same graph, but with x as the horizontal axis, such as shown in the figure below (this graph is from https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=area+between+the+curves+x%3Dy%5E2-2+and+y%3Dx)?

[image: Area between x=y^2-2 and x=y]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Do you want to change the PlotRange? `Show` adopts options from the first plot, so change `{y,-2,6}` to change x-axis range in `plot1`. If this does not work, then please edit the post and provide feedback. Also, why not use the `y=f[x]` convention while plotting? Thanks.

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{{1 - t, t} . {f[y], g[y]}, y}, {y, -1, 2}, {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: thank you @Syed for your response. Well in calculus textbook, you will find topics about area between two curves, whether it between two f(x) functions or between f(y) functions.  So i just want to know to replicate picture that i saw in the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible problems: the inverse of the first functions is 2- valued. Filling is in y direction, therefore, you must fill fom 1 to 3 and erease the superfluous part by a white filling from 2->3.

```
Plot[{Sqrt[x + 2], -Sqrt[x + 2], x}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRegion -> {-3, 3}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {3}, 2 -> {{3}, White}}]
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the code that you've added to get this graph. Perhaps its different the code from cvgmt, then maybe i can learn something useful from you code for my future need.

Comment: Sorry, I simply forgot to add the code.

Comment: thank you for your help @daniel

Answer (score 6):

We can use the `plot1`,`plot2`,`fill` by the author,and then replace `{x,y}` to `{y,x}`.

```
Show[{plot1, plot2, fill} /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {y, x}, Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, Automatic}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i want to achieve. Thank you for your help @cvgmt

Answer (score 4):

A variation of @cvgmt's approach using the option `DisplayFunction`:

```
Plot[{f @ y, g @ y}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {LightGreen, None}}},
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
 DisplayFunction -> ReplaceAll[c : {_Real, _Real} :> Reverse @ c]]
```

[image]

***Note:*** Alternatively, you can replace `ReplaceAll[c : {_Real, _Real} :> Reverse @ c]` with

```
(MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]] &, #, {1}] &)
```

Comment: (+1) `DisplayFunction`  is new to me.